# Data hiding worth for simple data containers

Tags: c++, oop, functional-programming

In my company, we generate code from XML. The code generator generates header files that contain Messages, and each message contains only data. NOTE we don't do any validation while setting or returning data; also, we don't have to take care of the state, i.e., data x and data in a message are independent; if x is changed, we don't need to change the state of y.

**Current header file**

```
class somemessage
{
private:
    Field _field;
    .......
public:
    Field& getfield(){...}
    const Field& getfield() const {...}
    void setfield(const Field& field){....}
} ;
```

Do we still need data hiding here if it's only data? Do we require getter and setters in these headers, or can se make it simple as following.

```
struct  somemessage
{
    Field field;
};
```

We can make the message read-only when required using const as following.

```
void message_consumer(const somemessage& message)
{
    message.field = somevalue; // compilation error
}
```

What are the disadvantages of this approach, and what are the advantages of using accessors and mutators?

Comment: encapsulation is not a must. It has lots of pros and some cons. Whehter you should use it or not is opinion-based.

Comment: fwiw, imho getters and setters is encapsulation gone wrong and you could make them public as well, especially as you are returning references. Once you returned a non-const reference all encapsulation is lost

Comment: If you have pass-through getters and setters then you aren't hiding any data.

Comment: Getter/setter pairs is the antithesis of encapsulation and data hiding.

Comment: On the more pragmatic side of the advantages, in many IDEs it's way easier to set function breakpoints then to set data breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following pattern:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void SetFoo(const Foo& newFoo) {
        f = newFoo;
    }
    const Foo& GetFoo() const {
        return f;
    }
protected:
private:
    Foo f;
};
```

That is, you have a getter/setter pair and all they do is have a single return statement and a single assignment expression, then there's no need for the data member to be private and instead just make the data member public and remove the getter/setter pair.

```cpp
class A {
public:
    Foo f;
protected:
private:
};
```

If your getters/setters do anything else, or are in any way more complicated, then yes, having a getter/setter pair is fine.

In terms of using a `struct` versus a `class`, I go with `struct` if the type is strictly only data; no functions, no constructors. If for whatever reason the data type needs functions, then it should be declared as a `class`.

Comment: This is semantically equivalent to the `struct somemessage`  the OP suggested

Comment: @CoryKramer Clarified struct vs class representation

Comment: The *only* difference between `struct` and `class` is default `public` vs `private` member visibility respectively. Any rules like "if it has methods" are an opinion-based distinction.

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes; but, in terms of comprehension and consistency if you consider `struct` to be just a collection of data members and `class` to be anything more complicated, you can understand the code quicker if and when you see `struct` you instantly know that "This type only has data members" and you don't have to worry about any other implementation details.

Comment: @Casey thats purely convention. I choose `struct` or `class` based on whether I want to list `private` or `public` members first. "when you see struct you instantly know that "This type only has data members"" is wrong in general. Of course if you stick to your convention it is fine, but still only a convention

Comment: Thanks, @Casey you understood my question correctly, and I am also thinking of implementing along the same line as you suggested.

Comment: @user982042 If this answer satisfied your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a getter like this:

```
Field& getfield(){...}
```

is *not* encapsulation. A user can do this:

```
Field& decapsulated = x.getField();
```

and now they have a reference to the private member that they can use to do what they like. All checking and bookkeeping in the setter is futile, because the user does not need it to modify the private member:

```
decapsulated = some_other_field;
```

Proper encapsulation has advantages. Though plain old structs with only public members have their place as well. If however all you do is writing boilerplate that does not encapsulate the data, you can leave away the boilerplate. Eventually it is up to you to decide what to use. Encapsulation has lots of advantages, but it is not a must.

Getters returning non-const references can be useful as convenience methods. They can provide easy means for the user to access the class data. Compare for example to `std::vector::operator[]` or `std::vector::at()`. Though one should not confuse that with data encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks @ber . If I remove the non-const accessor, still its worth to have class with getters and setters in this case ? If yes I would be very grateful if you can provide some use cases ?

Comment: @user982042 I am with moldbnilo when they write "Getter/setter pairs is the antithesis of encapsulation and data hiding." Though I tried to keep that out of the answer as it is borderline opinion based. Methods should be about behavior not about data.

Comment: @user982042 I remember an awesome 5 minutes talk from a conference where the speaker uses an analogy of a person going to a pub. Getters and setters are like the bartender opening your purse, counting the money that is inside, substracting what you have to pay and then putting the left over money back. When I go to a bar its more like I have a method `pay(amount)` rather than `get_money()` and `set_money(amount)`

Comment: @user982042 there is a wide spectrum between what I would consider object oriented and a data structure with all public members. There is no wrong or right, you just have to decide where on that spectrum your data structures are

Comment: @user982042 not the talk I remembered but same guy, same topic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMrjuuczZkQ eg 10:10 "getters and setters is a huge problem. Every time you see that you know it is not object oriented". I mean writing getters and setters can be ok-ish, just dont do it for its own sake or to add some object orientation to your code, because it is not

Comment: @user982042 well, to actually answer your question for use cases. Getters and setters can be useful in frameworks that rely on getters and setters. Outside of that I don't know good use cases from the top of my head.